# How can I add widgets to the category page?

Tags: widgets

At page `wp-admin/widgets.php` I can personalize the Widgets shown in the homepage of my website.

But I suspect I cannot use the same for any other page. I would like to create a page and put inside some widgets and use it as a category page for the category X. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a template for that X category where you can add a special dynamic sidebar and throw in the widgets you want? https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display

Comment: @samuel sorry for my lack of knowledge. Is this operation something like hardcoding the widget through some PHP code or I will be able to use the same tool I use for the homepage?

Comment: If I get you well, you are trying to show certain widgets in the x category page ( example: `news` category page ).. if that's the thread, then we will guide you set up a template for the category in your child theme..

Comment: @samuel yes, that is what I would like to do!

Comment: You will register a dynamic sidebar, make a custom template etc I don't think we will be able to trade everything in these comments. any way to contact you?
I hope I am not violating any network rule.